# Can I run a GA to optimize wavelet transform?

Tags: frequency, wavelet

I am running a wavelet transform (cmor) to estimate damping and frequencies that exists in a signal.cmor has 2 parameters that I can change them to get more accurate results. center frequency(Fc) and bandwidth frequency(Fb). If I construct a signal with few freqs and damping then I can measure the error of my estimation(fig 2). but in actual case I have a signal and I don't know its freqs and dampings so I can't measure the error.so a friend in here suggested me to reconstruct the signal and find error by measuring the difference between the original and reconstructed signal e(t)=|x(t)−x^(t)|. 
so my question is:
Does anyone know a better function to find the error between reconstructed and original signal,rather than e(t)=|x(t)−x^(t)|.
can I use GA to search for Fb and Fc? or do you know a better search method?
Hope this picture shows what I mean, the actual case is last one. others are for explanations[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think GA is not a suitable optimization algorithm for this problem. GA is mostly used when parameters to be optimized are a lot and when the objective function varies in a way which is not able to be tracked. I suggest you to use Wavelets with high accuracy.

Comment: @MahdiKhosravi hi, thanks for your answer. what is " Wavelets with high accuracy"? a new wavelet type or what?

Comment: I mean use Wavelets with higher resolution to get results with more accuracy.

Comment: @MahdiKhosravi I've done that already and the estimated parameters are accurate enough.But in this post I wanted to ask how can I optimize fc and fb(resolution) with another algorithm.

Comment: You can reconstruct signal from fc and fb and minimize the error between reconstructed signal and the original signal.

Comment: @MahdiKhosravi I am estimating the damping and freqs in a 1-D signal. so what is my error function? what is the function for finding the error between reconstructed signal and the original signal.

Comment: You can reconstruct signal from the estimated parameters then subtract it from the original to see how they are difference

Comment: @MahdiKhosravi , If original signal is x(t) and reconstruct signal is Xn(t) then I must minimize the error=x(t)-Xn(t) by changing Fb,Fc? also the error function is error=x(t)-Xn(t) or do you have a better idea

Comment: $e(t) = |x(t) - \hat x(t)|$. I don't have any better idea.

Comment: @MahdiKhosravi Look at my edit on the question please.

Comment: @MahdiKhosravi Hi. it seems matlab doesn't support complex morlet to reconstruct the signal. do you know how can I reconstruct it with coefficients?  http://www.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/icwtlin.html

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use GA or any other derivative-free optimization methods to solve your problem [[1]](http://www2.peq.coppe.ufrj.br/Pessoal/Professores/Arge/COQ897/dfo-Sahinidis.pdf). The correct parameter values can be determined using your application. If I'm trying to optimize for compression then I will look into the entropy of the resultant coefficients. Deciding on the actual values for your parameters will depend on how you plan to use them. The correct parameter values are simply the ones that work better.

Comment: I don't know enough about GA and search methods. I've just edited my post to get sure that my question is clear, Look at my edit please , and help me to implement GA or another search method. Tnx

Comment: How can I find the best wavelet parameters by entropy criterion? @hasan