# inverse continuous wavelet transform and [Parm] in cwtft

Tags: matlab, wavelet

what is '`parm`' means when you set the name of wavelet function in `cwtft` or `icwtft`. `wave = {wname,[7.6]}`. also can I change Fb and Fc when I use '`morl`' function in `cwtft` or `icwtft` transform? and If not, then how can I reconstruct my signal with `cwt` transform? cause cwt let me to select optional value for fb and fc (`cmorfb-fc`). Matlab doesn't have direct function for inverse wavelet transform.

```
N = 1024;
t = linspace(0,1,N);
y = sin(2*pi*8*t).*(t<=0.5)+sin(2*pi*16*t).*(t>0.5);
dt = 0.05;s0 = 2*dt;ds = 0.4875;NbSc = 20;
wname = 'morl';sig = {y,dt};sca = {s0,ds,NbSc};
wave = {wname,[7.6]};
cwtsig = cwtft(sig,'scales',sca,'wavelet',wave);
sigrec = icwtft(cwtsig,'signal',sig,'plot');
```

Comment: I have encountered the same problem! Have you figured out the way to deal with this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cwtft` and `icwtft` use Fourier transform of wavelet function to reconstruct the signal. The ‘`morl`’ in `wname` is analytic morlet function. So it’s exactly **complex morlet** and will give you phase and magnitude information about signal. The ‘`parm`’ in `wave={‘morl’,[parm]}` is wo or 2*pi*fc. So it’s corresponded to center frequency. Default value of ‘parm’ is 6 so fc=6/2*pi.molet wavelet function is psi(t,fc)=exp(j*2*pi*fc*t)*exp(-t^2/2) and its Fourier transform is psi^(k)=sqrt(2*pi)exp(-0.5(2*pi*k-ko)^2). `ko= parm = 2*pi*fc`. so you can config fc of morlet wavelet with changing parm.

Comment: this is the answer of question. thought you may need it. Also I don't know how to write formulation nice. anyone edit it please.

Answer (score 0):

Why won't cmorwavf work?

http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/wavelet/ref/cmorwavf.html

Could you then construct a matrix of (complex) Morlet wavelet co-efficients (suitably dilated and translated) and simply invert it for the inverse wavelet transform?

Comment: I can transform my signal with complex morlet continuous wavelet transform and obtain the coefficients in matlab. it has a easy code.But Matlab Wavelet Toolbox does not support the inverse CWT for a general CWT.this question appeared for me when I was trying to find an answer on this post: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/10583/can-i-run-a-ga-to-optimize-wavelet-transform  I thought its easy to reconstruct a signal when you have its coefficients but it seems its not easy. Thanks for reply

Comment: You could apply the wavelet transform to all colums of eye(N) to obtain an N dimensional wavelet trasform, I think

Comment: Can I get Inverse Continues wavelet transform this way? Would you explain more? what is N by the way?

Comment: As long as your matrix is square, the inverse transform should be as simple as inverting the matrix. This Haar matrix implementation may be helpful http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/33625-haar-wavelet-transformation-matrix-implementation/content/ConstructHaarWaveletTransformationMatrix.m.

Comment: I have looked at the codes. but didn't understand it well. I will try to understand it. but would you explain what he has done in the link you introduced?

Comment: aww I think he construct haar wavelet. it's different from what I want. I want to reconstruct my signal with inverse  complex morlet Cwt. constructing Complex morelet function is so easy but that's not my question. my question is like I have run fft for x(t) and now i want to run ifft to see my reconstructed signal.

Comment: He creates a matrix such that each row is Haar wavelet, and the transform and it's inverse are just done by matrix multiplication.

Comment: my signal x(t)--[complex morlet transform]--> Coefficients of x(t) 
now I want: Coefficients of x(t)--[inverse complex morlet transform]--> x^(t) . x^(t) must be similar to x(t) if I tuned complex morlet function well.

Comment: I understand what you want, and have how you could get it. I'm not prepared to give you matlab codes to solve it I'm afraid.